# Concise table names vs readability

Tags: database-design

So my database has `Users` and `Projects`.  We are using a singular convention and we have

```
User
Project
ProjectUserMapping
```

So far so good.  But now we have a lot of tables that relate to storing various data related for specific project/user pairings (yes, I know we could do all of the following in one table, but we chose not too)

```
ProjectUserIntegerAttribute
ProjectUserStringAttribute
ProjectUserDecimalAttribute
```

So we are coming up with a lot of `ProjectUserXXX` table names.  Some devs wan't to just get rid of the `ProjectUser` prefix, presumably for making code easier to write/read, yet I'm objecting because there are some tables (though they are in the minority) that are not a "ProjectUser" combination, and furthermore without the prefix you are not accurately describing the table?

The only happy medium I can think of is to use a  "PU" prefix as an abbreviation.  Should I still insist we use a prefix of some sort?

Comment: It's not really a database design issue, it's a naming convention issue. I don't imagine you will get an answer here.

Comment: ProjUsr.  notice this is a new table name that is not like User or Project.  Once the Project and User Join an important relationship is created that your abundance of tables is pointing out that it is an important relationship in your situation.  The corollary is that why do you have more than one table with Project and User in it.  Sounds like you already had the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

*Should I still insist we use a prefix of some sort?*

I know I would. Because tomorrow, somebody will need a `UserIntegerAttribute` or a `ProjectStringAttribute`.

Shorting them to PU might be a way out, if the letters "P" and "U" are extrmely likely to always be associated with "Project" and "User". But don't come back here and shout at me if you're having "Product" tables tomorrow and need `ProductUserIntegerAttributes`.

I personally prefer precision when it comes to persistent names such as global variables or database tables. Stuff with local scope can be short. My iterators tend to be *i, j* and *k*.

In the end, how often do you actually need to type table names? Probably not that often, so saving time on typing table names is unlikely to have a noticable effect on productivity.